# Find $E(Y)$, where $Z\sim N(0,1), Y=\max(Z-1,0)$

Tags: probability

Find $E(Y)$, where $Z\sim N(0,1), Y=\max(Z-1,0)$

I think I'm closing to solve problem. But I'm stuck somewhere.

**MY SOLUTION**
$$E(Y)=\int \max(z-1,0)\phi(z)dz$$,where $\phi(z)$ is p.d.f. of standard normal distribution.
$$\int \max(z-1,0)\phi(z)dz=\int_{1}^{\infty}(z-1)\phi(z)dz+\int_{-\infty}^{1}0\phi(z)dz$$
$$=\int_{1}^{\infty}z\phi(z)dz-\int_{1}^{\infty}\phi(z)dz$$
$$=\left.-\phi(z)\right\rvert_1^\infty-\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\frac{1}{-z}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}\right\rvert_1^\infty$$
$$=\frac{e^{-\frac {1}{2}}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}-\frac{e^{-\frac {1}{2}}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}=0$$
It is strange that result is $0$. Where am I missing? :(

Comment: This can't be right: the integrand is always $ge 0$ and sometimes actually strictly positive, so its integral cannot be $0$.

Comment: $\int \phi(z) \ dz \neq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{-z}e^{-z^2/2}$ in fact the Gaussian cdf $\Phi(z)$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at the numerical values for each integral, and you'll likely be able to see where you went wrong. I've put the actual error in the spoiler.

> You messed up with $$\int_1^\infty \phi(z)dz=-\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\frac{1}{-z}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}\right\rvert_1^\infty$$

> This isn't true, and you would instead need to use the CDF of the standard normal distribution for the integral.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so should I finally find the CDF from standard normal table or calculator?

Comment: @user170085 Yeah, however you prefer. I don't think there's a closed form for $\Phi(1)$.